# Why are my default values always null for checkbox/boolean fields?

Tags: custom-field, metadata, default-value, inputcheckboxes, boolean

I setup a field in Salesforce:

[image]

When looking at the metadata for my custom object containing this field, this is the data on that metadata field:

```
    "defaultValue": null,
    "defaultedOnCreate": true,
    "name": "ABI__c",
```

Why is the defaultValue null? Shouldn't it be false?

Using REST API v31.0

**Update:**
I tried defaulting the value to true/checked, but the defaultValue is still null.

**Update:**
This issue still exists in REST API v32.0

Comment: The problem is that a NULL and a FALSE checkbox value appear the same and can both be described as Unchecked. The more important question is what problems are you running into as a result of the NULL values.

Comment: @JosephU. thanks for the feedback. However, I tried setting the default value to true, and it is still null. (I posted a minor edit to my question saying so.)

Comment: Vote up this idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000HXSiAAO

Comment: @MarkMasterson thanks for the link, I upvoted the issue. I can't believe this bug has been around for years!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a way to get the default programmatically at this time, but there is an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000HXSiAAO) to get this changed.

Update: As noted in the idea comments, this has now grown up and become a real [Known Issue/Bug](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XL8AAM).

Comment: The sad truth :/